# bootstrap-4.1.3 fixed-bottom window hidden by browser extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I need a fixed-bottom window like this one:

```
<div class='clearfix fixed-bottom'>
     <span class='float-right' style='background-color:yellow'>Please do not hide me!</span>
</div>
```

The result is correct... until an unrelated firefox statusbar (from s3download-statusbar) appears and hides it.

I would like (by css and/or JS) to move up/down the little window, when the statusbar shows/hides, but strangely `window.innerHeight` and `$(window).height()` values are not impacted by the statusbar show/hide.

I also did not found any JS event to inform me that a statusbar (or any other window) was now hiding my window.

The little window is very important, its content must remain visible constantly: if other (unknown) browser extensions shows and hides, the fixed-bottom must move accordingly.

Users of this page have also chrome, IE, safari, ... therefore I'm looking for a solution valid for these browsers.

Comment: The extension was only an example. Many extensions on browsers add subwindows that reduces the viewport of your website. window.innerHeight is also supposed to return the real visible height of the viewport, which is not the case here.

Comment: According to all documentations i read, window.innerHeight is supposed to return the real visible height of the viewport, in ANY situation - but this is not the case here.

Comment: There are websites with a window in the lower right corner like this one, and when a statusbar show/hides, the little window moves up/down. How do you do that with bootstrap 4?